# Changing Ellipse color based on RoundTripTime property

Tags: c#, xaml

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="RoundTrip Time:                           " Style="{StaticResource tbStyle}" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="RoundTripEllipse" Fill="{Binding RTStatus}" Height="20" Stroke="Black" Width="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Property `RTStatus` is given below.

```
   public Brush RTStatus{
            get
            {
                if (RT_Time < 60)
                {
                    return Brushes.Green; // RoundTripStatus.green;
                }
                else if ((RT_Time > 60) && (RT_Time < 100))
                {
                    return Brushes.Orange;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-evaluate binding value you'll have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the view model as described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification).

Note you'll have to call `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, nameof(RTStatus))` every time the value of `RT_Time` changes.